# java.lang.NullPointerException while creating BinaryTree from preorder and inorder

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I don't know why this code is throwing a runtime error

```
    static class TreeNode<E>
{
    E data;
    TreeNode<E> right, left;
    
    TreeNode(E data)
    {
        this.data=data;
        right=left=null;
    }
}
```

inpte: To store inorder in a manually implemented LinkedList.
preptr: To store preorder in a manually implemented LinkedList.
num: To store the total number of nodes in the tree.

```
TreeNode<E> construct(Node<E> inptr, Node<E> preptr, int num)
{
    TreeNode<E> tmp;
    Node<E> q;
    int i,j;
    
    if(num==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No node to create the tree");
        return null;
    }
     
    
    tmp=new TreeNode<E>(preptr.data); //error line
    if(num==1)
        return tmp;
    
    q=inptr;
    for(i=0;q.data!=preptr.data;i++)
        q=q.next;
    
    tmp.left=construct(inptr, preptr.next, i);
    
    for(j=1;j<=i+1;j++)
        preptr=preptr.next;
    
    tmp.right=construct( q.next, preptr, num-i-1);
        
    
    return tmp;
}
```

error thrown:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at practiceCodes.PreAndIn.construct(PreAndIn.java:32)
    at practiceCodes.PreAndIn.main(PreAndIn.java:104)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preptr` on the line you highlighted is null. And it is null because you call `construct` recursively by doing `preptr.next` but there isn't always a `preptr.next` so you need to check whether `preptr.next` exists before calling `construct` or you need to check in `construct` if the arg is null, then do something meaningful for your case